# Its possible to force Routing traffic from vnet to on premises network via Ipsec POlicy based gateway

Tags: azure

How could i set up a forced route between a virtual network to force all the traffic to be routed to on premises network? Please more details bellow about the situation where i am:

Scenario: We have some VM's/kubernetes cluster / hosted on azure and we need to make sure that all traffic is routed to our on premises network, besides all critical/security reasons that we have, the one that is bugging me is mostly because that we have our cloud repository with whitelists enabled ( meaning that only specifics IP's can connect to our repo ) and since our CI process is deployed on kubernetes, we need to make sure that we are using our site 2 site gateway traffic in order to be able to connect to our repository:

Currentl, we are using a Policy based IpSec connection and for most of the documentation that im reading, it seems that is only possible to achieve the forced routing if we switch from POlicy based to route based gateway

Regarding visual representation, a simplification of what we have at the moment is:

[image]

And this is what im trying to achieve:

[image]

Regarding our setup, these are the implementations that we have in place for:

[IPsec connection to Microsoft Azure For SOphos UTM](https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/126995)

[Setup VPN gateway transit for virtual network peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit)

Comment: Good question, but I don't think it fits StackOverflow. FWIW, I think you might have to upgrade to Sophos XG Next Gen Firewall. Sophos UTM doesn't seem to have a software upgrade that lets it connect to a route-based VNET gateway.

Comment: pfSense (open source) supports route-based gateways. Maybe try putting a pfSense box at the office edge?